# which mysql.server should I use to restart mysql in MacOS?

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to restart mysql on my MacBook and I found this command:
`sudo /usr/local/mysql/support-files/mysql.server restart`

However, `/usr/local/mysql/support-files/mysql.server` does not exist in my mac. The following exists:

```
john@John-MacBook-Pro:~/Infervision/logs$ find / -name "*mysql.server"  2>/dev/null 
/usr/local/bin/mysql.server
/usr/local/Cellar/mysql/5.7.11/bin/mysql.server
/usr/local/Cellar/mysql/5.7.11/support-files/mysql.server
```

which one should I use?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use `brew` command for restarting your services installed using Brew. The command to restart MySQL would be:

`brew service restart mysql`

To list various services you can use:

`brew services list`